# Pass multiple values to meteor validate method

Tags: meteor

When I call a method I want to pass multiple values to the method using the call.  I'm not sure why it just errors `undfined`. If I only pass one value `profileCandidate` the method works.

Path: `imports/api/profileCandidate/methods.js`

```
export const insertProfileCandidate = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'profileCandidate.insert',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: { type: String },
    lat: { type: Number },
    lng: { type: Number },
  }).validator(),
  run({profileCandidate, lat, lng}) {
    ProfileCandidate.insert({
      userId: this.userId,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      name: {
        first: profileCandidate.firstName,
      },
      contact: {
        mobile: profileCandidate.mobile,
      },
      address: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
      }
    });
  },
});
```

Path: `imports/ui/ProfileCandidateForm.jsx`

```
var profileCandidate = this.state;

geocodeByAddress(this.state.address, (error, { lat, lng }) => {
  if (error) { return }

  if (!error) {
    insertProfileCandidate.call({profileCandidate, lat, lng}, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        alert(error.reason);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your validate function. Try this:

```
export const insertProfileCandidate = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'profileCandidate.insert',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
  profileCandidate: { type: Object },
    'profileCandidate.firstName': { type: String },
    lat: { type: Number },
    lng: { type: Number },
  }).validator(),
  run({ profileCandidate, lat, lng }) {
    console.log(profileCandidate, lat, lng)
  },
});
```

You have to explicitly define a validator for each field inside `profileCandidate` object like that.

Let me know...

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't realise I needed to specify `profileCandidate` as an `Object`. Thanks!